# LineJoiner in FME

Tags: fme-form

I have lot of line objects. Some of them are smaller than some criteria.

I would like to join all lines or smaller segments of line which are smaller than `1 meter` to bigger lines, keeping the attributes of the bigger line.

Any advice?

I tried to use first Tester to check length of the line objects (if it is smaller than 1 m), and than passed output goes to LineJoiner. But actually nothing happens, and lines which come from output port of LineJoiner do not have attributes as lines before (as they should have it). MAybe I complicate too much, but i thought this will be easy task.

Comment: Could you please clarify - do you want the bigger lines to take the attributes of the smaller lines they get joined to?

Comment: Opposite :) I need smaller lines join to bigger (1+5=6).

Comment: I know you want to merge the lines, but what do you want to happen to the attributes? Do you want to keep the attributes for the bigger line as they originally were or do you want to use the attributes from the smaller lines for new the big line?

Comment: Keep attributes from the bigger line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `LineJoiner` transformer with parameter `List Name`. But you need to do some additional data processing:

1. Use `LengthCalculator` to calculate lengths.
2. Use `Sorter` to sort your lines by length (numeric sort, descending).
3. Use `LineJoiner` to join lines. The biggest ones first (thanks to step 2). Specify parameter `List Name` of the `LineJoiner` - some name for new list attribute.
4. Use `ListIndexer` with list index 0 - to get the first joined feature (the biggest one) attributes' from the list.

Here is how it will look:
[image: model example]

**EDIT1:**

In order to be able to join only <1m features to bigger ones we need additionally to use:

1. `Tester` transformer after LengthCalculator with test: `_length < 1`
2. Use `SpatialFilter` (tests to perform parameter: `TOUCHES`) after Tester to filter only that features which touch features <1m. Then perform line joining on them together with <1m features. Features that don't touch <1m, direct to output (or further processing).

Model:
[image: model2]

**EDIT2:**

If you have <1m line that touches two big ones then they all will be joined together. If such case (<1m feature touches two or more big ones) is possible in your data then you should add some processing of such cases. Take a look at parameters `Merge Attributes` and `Attribute Prefix` of transformer `SpatialFilter`. Using these parameters you should be able to detect such cases and then do some additional filtering.

**EDIT3:**

Let's solve the case when you have two big lines touching one small (<1m). We need to take only one of the big lines to participate in joining with small one.

In order to be able to perform such filtering we need to mark these two big features with some id from small one they are touching. As stated in EDIT2, it can be done in `SpatialFilter` transformer using parameters `Merge Attributes` and `Attribute Prefix`.

Then use transformer `DuplicateRemover` to filter such duplicate features (two big) and take only one of them.

Hint: try to use `Inspector` transformer during creating your model and view intermediate results in any case that is not clear to you. In such way you will better understand how each of the transformers are working. Experiment with your data! :)

Comment: Ok. Thanl you for response. I will try this also.

Comment: But where do I suppose to set Tester (test which lines are smaller than 1 m)? because only those lines i will join to bigger lines?

Comment: Ok, this is a more complicated task. I have updated my answer. Idea is to use SpatialFilter and test for feature TOUCH. In such way we can supply to LineJoiner only <1m features and features that they touch.

Comment: Realized that even more complicated case is possible and added some info. Take a look.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It does not do full job. There are still lot of small lines which are not solved as it should be. I will take a better look and try to do some improvements possibly.

Comment: Is it possible that your data is inaccurate? try to use transformer `Snapper` before any processing.

Comment: How can I set picture here in comment?

Comment: You can edit your question and post there.

Comment: I am still checking results. There are many lines...

Comment: I have tried my proposed solution on test data - model is working ok. I suppose you need to check your data for topology errors. Try to Clip some small part of your data and test your model iteratively on it until you get fair results. Then apply it to the whole area.

Comment: Ok. But for example, If there is one small bit of line (<1m) between to bigger lines, small line will be joined to which bigger line (from left or from right side)?

Comment: I found case when join small line to both bigger lines (to the left and right side). This not good.

Comment: Thats why I have added EDIT2 section. If you fill `Merge Attributes` and `Attribute Prefix` then you will be able to mark such cases and get only one touching feature. Hint: use `DuplicateRemover` transformer.

Comment: oh, ok, will try

Comment: Further updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: I understand what is transformer Sorter doing. But is it necessery for it to be in this workbench? I tried without it, and do not see difference.

Comment: By `Sorter` we enforce features with more length going first to `LineJoiner` and then it's attributes will be with index "0" in the list (see parameter `List Name`) and then we can move them to feature's main attributes (`ListIndexer`). Otherwise you can have result where small features' attributes will "dominate". You can see no difference in case if big features go first, but I shall not relate on it.